# How to show only short keyboard layout in i3blocks with kbdd_layout?

Tags: keyboard, i3

I want to show the short discription of my current keyboard layout.

Currently it shows

```
Layout English (US)
```

or

```
Layout German
```

I would prefer `EN(US)` and `DE`.

I use the script from [kbdd_layout](https://github.com/vivien/i3blocks-contrib/tree/master/kbdd_layout). I could not figure out how the string is parsed and it would be great if someone would help me out.

Consider the code

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#    

killall kbdd 2>/dev/null
kbdd >/dev/null || exit 1

# Get initial state of layout
N=$( dbus-send --print-reply=literal --dest=ru.gentoo.KbddService\
    /ru/gentoo/KbddService ru.gentoo.kbdd.getCurrentLayout 2>/dev/null |\
    sed -un 's/^.*uint32 //p' )

# In case dbus service wasn't available yet, poll until service is ready
while [[ -z "$N" ]]; do
    sleep .1
    N=$( dbus-send --print-reply=literal --dest=ru.gentoo.KbddService\
        /ru/gentoo/KbddService ru.gentoo.kbdd.getCurrentLayout 2>/dev/null |\
        sed -un 's/^.*uint32 //p' )
done
echo $( dbus-send --print-reply=literal --dest=ru.gentoo.KbddService \
    /ru/gentoo/KbddService ru.gentoo.kbdd.getLayoutName uint32:$N )

# Parse dbus output
dbus-monitor "interface='ru.gentoo.kbdd',member='layoutNameChanged'" |\
sed -un '0~2p' | sed -un 's:.*string "\(.*\)".*:\1:p' | sed -u '/:/d'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did like follows (modified for your needs):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# 

killall kbdd 2>/dev/null
kbdd >/dev/null || exit 1

# Get initial state of layout
N=$( dbus-send --print-reply=literal --dest=ru.gentoo.KbddService\
    /ru/gentoo/KbddService ru.gentoo.kbdd.getCurrentLayout 2>/dev/null |\
    sed -un 's/^.*uint32 //p' )

# In case dbus service wasn't available yet, poll until service is ready
while [[ -z "$N" ]]; do
    sleep .1
    N=$( dbus-send --print-reply=literal --dest=ru.gentoo.KbddService\
        /ru/gentoo/KbddService ru.gentoo.kbdd.getCurrentLayout 2>/dev/null |\
        sed -un 's/^.*uint32 //p' )
done

dbus-send --print-reply=literal --dest=ru.gentoo.KbddService \
  /ru/gentoo/KbddService ru.gentoo.kbdd.getLayoutName uint32:$N |\
  sed -un 's:.*English.*:EN(US):p;s:.*German.*:DE:p'

# Parse dbus output 
dbus-monitor "interface='ru.gentoo.kbdd',member='layoutNameChanged'" |\
  sed -un 's:.*English.*:EN(US):p;s:.*German.*:DE:p'
```

Just remember to tweak the script accordingly, in case if you will change layouts.