# How to update i3blocks when switching layouts?

Tags: shell-script, keyboard, i3

I have two different keyboard layouts and I switch between them with *Ctrl+Shift*. And I want to display my current layout with i3blocks. Now I have a super small single-line script that returns current layout with the following command:

```
xkb-switch
```

But how can I update information when switching between keyboards?
What I've tried:

### Attempt #1

I could successfully update information by setting in *i3blocks.conf*:

```
[language]
interval=1
```

... which forces my blocks to run the script every millisecond. It works ok but I'm really not sure it's the proper way to do that, particularly on the laptop.

### Attempt #2

I also tried to send a signal to the block when pressing *Ctrl+Shift* with something like this in my *i3/config*:

```
bindsym --release Control+Shift exec --no-startup-id pkill -RTMIN+8 i3blocks
```

And with the following lines in *i3blocks.conf*:

```
[language]
interval=once
signal=8
```

But I couldn't make it work. If I change `Control+Shift` keys to any other key (for example `$mod+Shift+z` or `CapsLock` or `Control+1`) it works ok. 
(I mean, it sends a signal and updates blocks. If I switch keyboard with *Ctrl+Shift* and then press *Mod+Shift+z* or *CapsLock* or *Ctrl+1* it will send a signal, update i3blocks and the language block will change).

### Other

I saw [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356410/how-to-show-only-short-keyboard-layout-in-i3blocks-with-kbdd-layout) post. It's also about switching the layouts. But I couldn't relate this to my problem. I'm not the best bash-programmer and don't understand what's going on in this kbdd-script. As far as I understand there's nothing about my problem.

Comment: Okay, I've asked another question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363263/can-i-map-something-to-ctrlshift-in-i3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good guy on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/69eyfh/i3blocks_and_keyboard_layout/dh6j7lg/) helped me to solve the problem. I'll just copy-paste his answer here.
The crucial command:

```
xkb-switch -W
```

With the following lines in *i3blocks.conf* everything works like a dream.

```
# AUR package: xkb-switch-git
[keymap]
label=⌨
command=xkb-switch -W
#or
#command=bash -c 'xkb-switch;xkb-switch -W'
interval=persist
border=#0d5eaf
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen your question [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/69eyfh/i3blocks_and_keyboard_layout/) and if you are indeed using i3 I'm pretty sure you can edit the keymap of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> (the keymap is in the i3 config file too `~/.config/i3/config`) to run a script of yours instead, script that changes the layout AND notifies the bar.

Comment: As I described above I tried to map my keys with `bindsym` in the config file. It works with other keys but it doesn't work with *Ctrl+Shift*. Maybe there's something special about *Ctrl+Shift*?

Comment: I think the problem might be because CTRL and SHIFT are both dead keys. And i3 might be having trouble picking up a dead-keys only combination. I have two keyboard layouts too, and I use the windows default keybinding `Super + Space`

Comment: Yes, you're right! On my other [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363263/can-i-map-something-to-ctrlshift-in-i3/363304#363304) is a clear the explanation why.