# Can I map something to Ctrl+Shift in i3?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, i3

I want to run my script when pressing *Ctrl+Shift* in i3. But when I'm trying to map a custom command to *Ctrl+Shift* in *~/.config/i3/config* it doesn't work. For example:

```
bindsym Control+Shift exec chromium
```

- I thought maybe you can't `bindsym` without `$mod`, but
  `Control+1` works fine.
- `$mod+Control+Shift` also works.

---

I asked a [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363003/how-to-update-i3blocks-when-switching-layouts) recently but then realized maybe I'm asking the wrong one.

Comment: Oh no, the question was right! Though I can't map *Ctrl+Shift* I solved my previous problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

short: no

long:

<kbd>*Control*</kbd> and <kbd>*Shift*</kbd> are usually just ***modifiers***

That is, they are applied to a non-modifier key, such as your example **`1`**.

The i3 user guide tells you which keys are modifiers, in [Section 4.3](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#keybindings):

```
Available Modifiers:

Mod1-Mod5, Shift, Control

    Standard modifiers, see xmodmap(1)
```

as well as mentioning the syntax:

```
bindsym [--release] [<Group>+][<Modifiers>+]<keysym> command
```

While you could in principle change your keyboard configuration (so that those keys could be treated differently), you'd find it inconvenient to use i3 and other applications without the modifiers.